# UDP RecvBufErrors due to pfmalloc pages in lightly-loaded machine

Tags: linux-kernel

My linux box is dropping UDP packets. It has a 10GbeE 82599ES NIC with `ixgbe` driver.

Running `nc` to receive packets like this:

```
$ nc -I 100000000 -l 2004 -u > /dev/null
```

and sending packets from a different machine with:

```
$ cat /dev/zero | nc 10.5.10.248 2004 -u
```

has the RcvbufErrors on the receiving machine in `/proc/net/snmp` increasing like mad. Interestingly `/proc/net/udp` shows no dropped packets.
My kernel version is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux titan 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As far as I can tell, the only way to get RcvbufErrors without UDP drops is if [sk_filter](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/filter.c?v=3.16#L118) returns `-ENOMEM` in [sock_queue_recv_skb](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/sock.c?v=3.16#L437), which happens if the socket buffer page is `pfmemalloc`ed, which in turn happens if the machine is under memory pressure.

The weird thing is that `free` says there's loads of space:

```
$ free -m
total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32210      32016        194        178        352      29948
-/+ buffers/cache:       1715      30495
Swap:        65467        162      65305
```

Help?! (Thanks in advance)

K